# Get string from userInfo Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, swift, option-type

I have a userInfo dictionary from a UILocalNotification.  Is there an easy way to get the String value when using implicit unwrapping?

```
if let s = userInfo?["ID"]
```

Gives me a AnyObject that I have to cast to a string.

```
if let s = userInfo?["ID"] as String
```

Gives me an error about StringLiteralConvertable

Just didn't want to have to declare two variables to get a string - one literal for the unwrap and another var for the casted string.

Edit

Here is my method.  This doesn't work either - I get (NSObject, AnyObject) is not convertible to String on the if statement.

```
  for notification in scheduledNotifications
  {
    // optional chainging 
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo

    if let id = userInfo?[ "ID" ] as? String
    {
      println( "Id found: " + id )
    }
    else
    {
      println( "ID not found" )
    }
  }
```

I don't have it in my question, but besides getting this way to work, I'd like to actually have

```
if let s = notification.userInfo?["ID"] as String
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to use a *condition cast* using `as?`:

(Note: This works for Xcode 6.1.  For Xcode 6.0, see below)

```
if let s = userInfo?["ID"] as? String {
    // When we get here, we know "ID" is a valid key
    // and that the value is a String.
}
```

This construct safely extracts a string from `userInfo`:

- If `userInfo` is `nil`, `userInfo?["ID"]` returns `nil` due to *optional chaining* and the *conditional cast* returns a variable of type `String?` that has a value of `nil`.  The *optional binding* then fails and the block is not entered.
- If `"ID"` is not a valid key in the dictionary, `userInfo?["ID"]` returns `nil` and it proceeds like the previous case.
- If the value is another type (like `Int`), then the *conditional cast* `as?` will return `nil` and it proceeds like the above cases.
- Finally, if `userInfo` is not `nil`, and `"ID"` is a valid key in the dictionary, and the type of the value is a `String`, then the *conditional cast* returns an optional string `String?` containing the string.  The *optional binding* `if let` then unwraps the `String` and assigns it to `s` which will have type `String`.

---

For Xcode 6.0, there is one additional thing you must do.  You need to conditionally cast to `NSString` instead of to `String` because `NSString` is an object type and `String` is not.  They apparently improved that handling in Xcode 6.1, but for Xcode 6.0 do the following:

```
if let s:String = userInfo?["ID"] as? NSString {
    // When we get here, we know "ID" is a valid key
    // and that the value is a String.
}
```

Finally, addressing your last point:

```
  for notification in scheduledNotifications
  {
      if let id:String = notification.userInfo?["ID"] as? NSString
      {
          println( "Id found: " + id )
      }
      else
      {
          println( "ID not found" )
      }
  }
```

Comment: This did not work.  I posted my function.  Also, I don't have it in the original question, but I originally wanted to access userInfo from the notification.  So notification.userInfo["ID"].

Comment: Thanks.  I was using Xcode 6.0.1.  Upgraded to 6.1 and it worked.